# Printing Custom Attribute of a product on My Downloadable Products page

Tags: attributes, downloadable, product-attribute

I have a custom product attribute of code `format` for all Downloadable Products.

If a customer purchases a Downloadable Product, I want them to be able to see that attribute when they Download the product in the  "My Downloadable Products" section, in `app/.../template/downloadable/customer/products/list.phtml`

Is there a way I can print that attribute in that template file, within the `foreach $_items as $_item` loop?

I have tried `$_item->getData('format');` and `$_item->getPurchased->getData('format');` and neither are working. I assume the problem is because only certain attributes are being loaded in this view at present but I am not sure how to load them.

Many thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the attribute is used in product listing:

Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > Select your `format` Attribute

Used in Product Listing set to "Yes".

You should be able to retrief the attribute value with `$_item->getData('format');`  or `$_item->getFormat();` then.